# Error while creating an array of objects in angular typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

Angular object-array creation error.
The data i want to represent is of the form :

```
stats : [
    {
        name : 'x', 
        age : 20
    },
    {
        name : 'y', 
        age : 10
    },
];
```

So in angular, I have defined it as :

```
stats: Array<{ name: string,  age : number }> = [];
```

so when i try to assign something to it like this :

```
this.stats[0]['name'] = 'x';
```

this throws an error :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined

ps : I don't want an alternate solution to this problem, as I need this sort of representation and data binding for my work.
and, also I cannot predefine the 'stats' array because the data inside it is dynamic and I don't have a fixed size.

Comment: please don't SHOUT. you could use **bold** or *emphasis* the text, instead of using all caps.

Comment: What's wrong? what does shout mean here?

Comment: Read a javascript tutorial. Any non-terrible one should cover your case.

Comment: @MehulL Words written in UPPERCASE are as they were shouted.

Comment: Oh i am sorry. This is the first time i have posted a question. I am not familiar with the pattern followed here.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Hey, i checked a lot of blogs & pages, but dint find the relevant answer. It would be great if any one could help.

Comment: `[][0]` is the first element of an empty array. You have something empty and take out the first, what do you get?

Comment: ok so how do i resolve it ? i have tried creating a class, interface. I get the same error. The array is dynamic, therefore cannot predefine. And i need to 2 way bind it. Please suggest if there is any thing i can do here.

Answer (score 1):

```
stats: Array<{ name: string, age : number }> = [];
```

Means you define an array of anonymous objects, with a name and an age property within each elements of the array.

To assign 'x' to the name property of the first index you have to write:

```
this.stats[0] = { name: 'x', age: 10 };
```

If you don't want to specify the age you have to define it as an optional property like so:

```
stats: Array<{name: string, age?: number}> = [];
```

Question mark was added.
Not sure but I believe it's good practice to define a named object and declare you array like :

```
stats: Stat[];
```

At least that's how I learned it.

Comment: alright thanks for that. I have got a bit of clarity in that. But then the next problem would be how do i bind it directly to a input field.
example,
i have an input field like ::
<input [(ngModel)]="stats[selectedIndex].name">
So whenever the user enter a value ,
it should get stored in the variable, stats[selectedIndex].name
  This is required because 'selectedIndex' is the selected player. and the user can choose any player from the list and enter the stats.

Comment: As @Vikas answered, I believe you have to bind to an existing (instantiated) object. There could be workaround with Observables depending on your business logic (please note Angular 6.0 introduce new ways with rxjs).

Answer (score 0):

Define an Interface and instantiate your object before Binding it

```
export class AppComponent  {

     stats:Array<Idata>=[];
     constructor(){
       this.stats[0]={name:'x',age:10}
       console.log(this.stats[0].name)
       console.log(this.stats[0].age)
     }

    }

    export interface Idata{
      name:string,
      age:number,
    }
```

**Binding to input field**

```
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="stats[0].name">
```

**[Working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ez4drw)**

Comment: Hi if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.